# What can be reason behind of almost all structures being incomplete type in Kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, typedef

I'm porting some functionality for the kernel for whatever reason and I came across loads of error messages. Most of which I've fixed.

I'm mostly working on header files to tune them to my needs. Getting about 92 of following error messages:

`include/linux/dax.h:66:26: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
include/linux/highmem.h:67:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
include/linux/pagemap.h:66:28: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
include/linux/backing-dev-defs.h:191:22: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
include/linux/writeback.h:217:13: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
include/linux/blkdev.h:972:32: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
include/linux/fsnotify_backend.h:317:13: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
include/linux/fsnotify.h:218:12: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
include/linux/fs.h:776:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
include/linux/backing-dev.h:66:45: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type`

Any protip on how to fix it without rewriting yet again loads of functionality?
There's a lot of structures usage in those headers files. For examples :

```
struct page;
```

Comment: Include the header file which defines the structure?

Comment: Problem is I do. I had a lot of problems with `linux/fs.h` because nothing from there was seen by linux/dax.h for example, had to spend extra time to make it stop spamming errors. Although maybe I'm not including somewhere else. I've lost clue at this point (probably with parts of my sanity).

Comment: IIRC many of the headers rely on an `#ifdef` to provide definitions for kernelspace-only data structures only when compiling the kernel. The headers installed in `/usr/include/linux` might even have the kernelspace parts removed.

Comment: That would be correct from my observation. I might have misplaced some of the ifdefs doing my changes so I'll start there tomorrow and see if it helps.

Comment: So you mess with the headers of a very large project and wonder why you get a bunch of errors? Simply **don't** unles you have understood it completely!

Comment: Lesson learned the hard way. Turned out I've made too big of a mess to notice that few structures are either non-existent or not included at all. So I started rewriting everything taking better notice of which changes I'm making.
Thanks for being patient with me :)
Cheers.